# Inserting large amount of records into Sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro, async-await

In my Windows 8 metro app I have a table in a SQLite database on occasion will have to be updated with a large amount of records (around 500 to 600).  I get the records from a web service and I loop through the records and insert them into a table.  The problem is that this operation is taking about 10 to 15 seconds and it is locking the UI including the progress bar.  The code is below.

```
await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    foreach (var item in body3)
    {
        db.Insert(new Site
           {
              siteName = item.siteName,
              siteAddress = item.siteAddress,
              siteCity = item.siteCity,
              siteState = item.siteState,
              siteID = item.siteID
           });
        progressBar.Value = i;                                
        i++;
    }
});
```

I'm thinking it's a problem with SQLite.  I can't seem to catch exceptions from it either.

I think my real question here is how to get this to run correctly in another thread so it doesn't affect the UI. I'm not that concerned that it takes a while to insert the records. I just want the UI to stay responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in this way.

```
foreach (var item in body3)
{
    db.RunInTransaction(() =>
    {
        db.Insert(new Site
        {
            siteName = item.siteName,
            siteAddress = item.siteAddress,
            siteCity = item.siteCity,
            siteState = item.siteState,
            siteID = item.siteID
        });
    });
    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        progressBar.Value = i;                                
        i++;
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually what worked better is wrapping the foreach loop in a transaction.  Now the process is so fast I don't need the progress bar anymore.  It went from around 10 to 15 seconds to less than a second.

Comment: Downvoted... it makes no sense to have your Transaction inside the Foreach loop! This will create a new connection / transaction per row and won't be any faster than what the OP did. Per Brian's comment - the foreach goes inside the transaction. Or, simply use SQLiteConnection.InsertAll(Collection).

Answer (score 3):

--don't update your UI from every insert in the loop... maybe every 20% if it's needed at all

--Use a transaction --
http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html #19
and here [Improve INSERT-per-second performance of SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite)

Comment: Those are great articles.  They should help a lot.  Thanks.